# How to whitelist google assistant in a private network?

Tags: actions-on-google, private-network

We are calling apis which are hosted in a private network from the actions/ dialogue flow console.

The apis are getting 403 as Actions on google/ dialog flow is not whitelisted.

To whitelist the same I need an ASN
(IP range is not going to work as Google has a dynamic IP range not a static one)

I require the steps to identify the ASN.

I have tried searching on the internet as well as the google documentation, was unable to find anything on it.

I wrote to `support@dialogflow.com` and they weren't able to help me out

Comment: you can filter the IP from request what ever is coming in your webhook